# std::string[] member deallocation fails during exception thrown from constructor

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, try-catch, stdstring

Using Visual Studio 2015 (update 3) I have a problem in a larger project which i boiled down to the minimal example down below.

Therein i have a class Test containing a std::string[3]. It may so happen, that the constructor of Test throws an exception, which i would like to deal with at the top level (main). However, when throwing from the constructor, an assertion in xmemory fails - it seems to me while trying to unwind and deallocate the std::string[3] (see console output and stack trace below). The catch statement is never reached and in a release built it just crashes.

When i replace the std::string[3] by a single std::string, the catch statement is correctly reached. Also, when throwing an exception from another member function called externally after construction is finished the catch block is reached as expected if using std::string[3].

**What is going on here?**
Any help appreciated.

The minimal example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vcruntime_exception.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>



class Test {
public:
    Test() {
        // throw exception from constructor
        throw std::exception("TestException");
    }

    ~Test() {
        std::cout << "Destruction" << std::endl;
    }

    //std::string mySingleString = "SingleTestString";
    std::string myStrings[3] = { "String1", "TestString2", "AnotherTestString" };
};


int main()
{
    try
    {
        Test* t = new Test();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        // this is never reached while std::string myStrings is not uncommented
        std::cout << "Caught:" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Caught an alien!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The console output:

```
Ausnahme ausgelöst bei 0x773CDDC2 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++-Ausnahme: std::exception bei Speicherort 0x0019FB8C.
"ConsoleApplication1.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication1.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication1.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication1.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication1.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication1.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication1.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...15\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0
Line: 100

Expression: "(_Ptr_user & (_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT - 1)) == 0" && 0
```

The stack trace:

```
ConsoleApplication1.exe!std::_Deallocate(void * _Ptr, unsigned int _Count, unsigned int _Sz) Zeile 99   C++
ConsoleApplication1.exe!std::allocator<char>::deallocate(char * _Ptr, unsigned int _Count) Zeile 720    C++
ConsoleApplication1.exe!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate(char * _Ptr, unsigned int _Count) Zeile 988 C++
ConsoleApplication1.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Tidy(bool _Built, unsigned int _Newsize) Zeile 2260  C++
ConsoleApplication1.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >() Zeile 1018 C++
ConsoleApplication1.exe!`eh vector destructor iterator'(void * ptr, unsigned int size, unsigned int count, void(*)(void *) destructor)  C++
ConsoleApplication1.exe!_main() C++
ConsoleApplication1.exe!main() Zeile 27 C++
```

Comment: Why are you using a raw array of strings at all?

Comment: First of all, it is not my code and secondly why not?

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug. `std::array<std::string, 3>` might get around the problem.

Comment: Does it happen if you don't use default member initializers?

Comment: _"this is never reached while std::string myStrings is not uncommented"_ Too many negatives; broke my brain :D

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It seems to work correctly when not using default initializers... but why?!

Comment: @Thomas Cos they broke :D (I had a very similar issue in GCC with `{}` as default value for a function argument [[ref](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60367)])

Comment: Could not make it work with member initializer list. Same error.

Comment: @Thomas If you are asking why your compiler has a bug, it's likely because nobody has reported it or the implementer hasn't invested the resources necessary to fix it. Though there are newer version of Visual Studio and it might be fixed in newer versions.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am merely asking if there is any possibilty that i did sth wrong and by some rule i must not use default initializers in this way/with std::string/on wednesdays. If everyone agrees its a compiler bug at least i can sleep well and work around it ;)

Comment: If you're breaking a rule somewhere, I can't see it. I duplicate the problem with MSVC 2015 Update 3. Don't have 2017 spun up anywhere I can try it out.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I hate std:string anyway, using const char* is better.

Comment: Is `std::exception("TestException")` a new kind of constructor for std::exception?

Comment: @Eljay Not new, but [a VS extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/exception-class?view=vs-2017)

Comment: @Thomas That's an extremely unpopular opinion with regards to c++. This isn't a bug with `std::string`. If you *just* mean for representing string literals, then `const char*` isn't so bad.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Actually `std::string` is quite unpopular overall, although granted for more than storing a literal I'm not sure many would recommend C-strings over it :D Mind you, now that we have `std::string_view`, I'm enjoying good old-fashioned `char` buffers more and more.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux What i meant was not that i hate C++, the std or std::string in general, but for this use case i would prefer const char* as nothing string-related is done with those strings anyway (they're just passed on). My comment was a little unspecific there.

Comment: @Thomas, it looks like a bug in compile. I test in in XCode and works. It seems that the problem is at the moment to release the local memory, in this case the array of strings `myStrings` which is create before the constructor is invoked. Due to the constructor is not ended successfully, the  instance of the class was not created. So, the question is: What happened with the compiler at the moment to release the memory, of `myStrings`, in this case?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the commenters this turned out to most likely be a problem with default member initializers and Visual Studio 2015.

Without default initializers it works.